# Is it possible to return a trait from a trait that depends on the arguments?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I have two operators over an `Iterator` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e31f7a5e1abc21eed8b2b76fc8607b3b))

```
fn begins_with<'a, I>(lines: I, query: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String> + 'a,
{
    // Some whatever filtering
    lines.filter(move |line| line.starts_with(&query))
}

fn whatever<'a, I>(lines: I, query: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String> + 'a,
{
    // Some whatever operation
    let mut sorted: Vec<String> = lines.collect();
    sorted.sort_unstable();
    sorted.into_iter().map(|s| s.to_lowercase())
}
```

I would like to be able to use one or the other and apply them on an iterator of `String`

One possibility is to use an `enum` like so ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a130c43cedbfe961aff5ebf0da348203)):

```
pub enum Operator {
    BeginsWith,
    Whatever,
}

fn operate<'a, I>(operator: Operator, lines: I, query: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String> + 'a,
{
    match operator {
        Operator::BeginsWith => begins_with(lines, query),
        Operator::Whatever => whatever(lines, query),
    }
}
```

But I get the following error (which is fair)

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/lib.rs:30:31
   |
28 | /     match operator {
29 | |         Operator::BeginsWith => begins_with(lines, query),
   | |                                 ------------------------- this is found to be of type `impl std::iter::Iterator`
30 | |         Operator::Whatever => whatever(lines, query),
   | |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found a different opaque type
31 | |     }
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `impl std::iter::Iterator` (opaque type)
              found type `impl std::iter::Iterator` (opaque type)
```

Another approach would be to make a trait and have implementations of it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f37a94cd572b36522ee0136b7aeda26e)):

```
pub trait Operator {
    pub fn operate<'a, I>(lines: I, query: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String> + 'a;
}
```

But this is not allowed in Rust.

What mechanisms does Rust provide for me to return an `Iterator` that depends on the arguments passed into the method implemented from a trait?

Comment: You deleted your previous question before I could reply to your comment, but I still believe this is a duplicate of [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423). Yes, that question asks specifically about an iterator, but the question and answer can be extended to any trait.

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c191eb1cb008a37cc6f63b71528a799)

Comment: As already suggested, voting as a duplicate of [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001592/why-can-impl-trait-not-be-used-to-return-multiple-conditional-types)

Comment: See also [Why can impl trait not be used to return multiple / conditional types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001592/155423); [Using impl Trait in Trait definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39482131/155423)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001592/why-can-impl-trait-not-be-used-to-return-multiple-conditional-types does solve my problem and I will mark this as duplicate. Is a level of indirection the only way to achieve this, then?

Comment: For now, yes. See [Is it possible to use `impl Trait` as a function's return type in a trait definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490692/155423) for a nightly-only solution that may be what you want.