# How to add lifetime Parameter to Box<> with dyn type alias

Tags: rust, lifetime, trait-objects

I have an type alias for a Fn trait like `type SomeSub = dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str;` which I would like to use with a Box with an explicit lifetime like `Box<SomeSub + 'b>`. Unfortunately this doesn't compile:

```
type SomeSub = dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str;

struct SomeBuilder(pub usize);

impl SomeBuilder {
    // --> this gets rejected with "type aliases cannot be used as traits"
    fn get_closure<'o>(
        &'o self
    ) -> Box<dyn SomeSub + 'o> {
        Box::new(|s| &s[self.0..])
    }

    // This works, but duplicates the code of the type alias
    fn get_closure_long<'o>(
        &'o self
    ) -> Box<dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str + 'o> {
        Box::new(|s| &s[self.0..])
    }
}
```

While the second method `get_closure_long()` compiles, `get_closure()` results in the error:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found type alias `SomeSub`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:18
  |
8 |     ) -> Box<dyn SomeSub + 'o> {
  |                  ^^^^^^^ type aliases cannot be used as traits
```

Leaving out the `dyn` like `-> Box<SomeSub + 'o>` will be rejected with "type aliases cannot be used as traits". Using `Box<SomeSub>` works bot doesn't allow the closure to capture any references.

What is the correct way to combine a closure type alias with a Box and an explicit lifetime for that box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the type alias generic:

```
type SomeSub<'b> = dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str + 'b;
```

Then `SomeSub<'o>` is a valid type that includes the lifetime, so this compiles:

```
fn get_closure<'o>(&'o self) -> Box<SomeSub<'o>> {
    Box::new(|s| &s[self.0..])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4f9a5ad1109f13bf390a0ca761156e13)

Alternatively, you can emulate a trait alias using the technique shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64991065/1600898):

```
trait SomeSub: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str {}

impl<T> SomeSub for T where T: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str {}
```

Then your original `get_closure()` that returns `Box<dyn SomeSub + 'o>` compiles.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8fd9703c36d8690fdc7a278a6b11d61)