# Why is impl Trait on extension methods not allowed?

Tags: methods, rust, traits

I find the distinction between the following two cases to be very strange

This code compiles

```
fn foobar() -> impl Fn() {
    || () 
}
```

but this code is not

```
trait Foo {
    fn bar() -> impl Fn() {
        || ()
    }
}
```

Why is this? And is there a way to get around this without forcing prefix function call notation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use \`impl Trait\` as a function's return type in a trait definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482131/is-it-possible-to-use-impl-trait-as-a-functions-return-type-in-a-trait-defini)

Comment: Why? Because `impl Trait` just says some concrete `T` where `T: Trait` that is decided by the body of the function but not named and changeable without externally visible (semver) changes. Now, if something implementing that trait, how would it know what type to return from `foobar`?. The workaround? `-> Box<dyn Fn()>`

Comment: @Caesar Are extension methods allowed to be overwritten? This isn't just a method that must be implemented for the trait, it is a definition I provide?

Comment: It turns out, extension methods can be overwritten, this is quite unfortunate