# How can I convert a Rust function with a single reference argument to a trait on the argument type?

Tags: rust

I have the following function, which does not have an "explicit" return type, only `Result<impl Iterator<Item = Commit>>` because Iterator types are unwieldy to deal with:

```rust
pub fn commits(repo: &Repository) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = Commit>> {
    let head_ref = repo
        .head_commit()
        .context("No HEAD commit found! Does the repository contain commits?")?
        .id();
    let state = ancestors::State::default();
    Ok(
        Ancestors::new(std::iter::once(head_ref), state, |oid, buf| {
            repo.objects.find_commit_iter(oid, buf)
        })
        .filter_map(|oid| repo.find_object(oid.ok()?).ok()?.try_into_commit().ok()),
    )
}
```

However, since this function takes a single reference to a `Repository` as its argument, it would make sense to implement a trait on `Repository` which returns this iterator.

I have tried to define the following trait, analogous to the function signature:

```rust
trait CommitIter {
    fn commits(&self) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = Commit>>;
}
```

However, the compiler gives me the following error: "error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in trait method return types". I understand that at trait definition time, the compiler *cannot* know yet what type I will be returning in the trait implementation and so the type cannot be known.

I know that I could `Box` the returned iterator, i.e `Result<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Commit>>` but I would like to avoid heap allocations if at all possible.

I can use generic types to make a valid trait like this:

```rust
trait CommitIter<'a> {
    fn commits<I>(&self) -> Result<I>
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = Commit<'a>>;
}
```

As far as I understand this changes the meaning of the `commits` function to be able to return an iterator of *any* type. I only want to implement the function for a *specific* type, I just want the compiler to figure out what type I mean.

How can I rewrite the above function as a trait on `Repository` without allocating on the heap, and without writing out the entire type of the returned Iterator? If this is impossible, what is the idiomatic way to deal with cases like this?

Edit: I am amending this question to clarify why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482131/is-it-possible-to-use-impl-trait-as-a-functions-return-type-in-a-trait-defini) does not answer my question.

Firstly, I already mentioned that the solution "use a `Box`" is highly undesirable for me. I do not want to allocate on the heap, or really change the functionality of the code in any way (disqualifies https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490692/12125728).

I do not just return `Self`, so the accepted answer in the original thread also does not apply here (disqualifies https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482164/12125728).

I tried using an associated type, as suggested by [Jeremy Salwen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174171/12125728) in the other thread like this:

```rust
trait CommitIter<'a> {
    type FReturn: Iterator<Item = Commit<'a>>;
    fn get_commit_iter(&'a self) -> Result<Self::FReturn>;
}
```

However, trying to implement the trait I have the same problem as specifiying the type in the trait definition: "error[E0658]: `impl Trait` in associated types is unstable":

```rust
impl<'a> CommitIter<'a> for Repository {
    type FReturn = impl Iterator<Item = Commit<'a>>;
    fn get_commit_iter(&self) -> Result<Self::FReturn> {
        let head_ref = self
            .head_commit()
            .context("No HEAD commit found! Does the repository contain commits?")?
            .id();
        let state = ancestors::State::default();
        Ok(
            Ancestors::new(std::iter::once(head_ref), state, |oid, buf| {
                self.objects.find_commit_iter(oid, buf)
            })
            .filter_map(|oid| self.find_object(oid.ok()?).ok()?.try_into_commit().ok()),
        )
    }
}
```

As Jeremy Salwen points out in his answer, I'd have to explicitly specify the return type in the trait implementation which I cannot do because it is an Iterator of some type like `FilterMap<Ancestors<{closure#35}, fn(&oid) -> bool, State>, {closure#36}>` according to rust-analyzer.

I assume this is the "boilerplate code" Sven Marnach refers to in the comments but I do not understand what that boilerplate code would have to be in my case to make the compiler happy.

Comment: Do the answers on this question help? [Is it possible to use `impl Trait` as a function's return type in a trait definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482131/is-it-possible-to-use-impl-trait-as-a-functions-return-type-in-a-trait-defini)

Comment: The summary is: You can either return `Box<dyn Trait>` and accept the cost of dynamic dispatch, or accept a bit of boilerplate code. In almost all cases, the cost of dynamic dispatch is irrelevant, so that's the easiest solution.

Comment: I have edited the question to try and clarify why the answers to the linked question do not help me. I am absolutely willing to accept some boilerplate code but I do not know what that boilerplate code would need to be, since as I explained I cannot specifiy the explicit type in the implementation.

Comment: There is no good solution here. Either use dynamic dispatch, or use nightly. There is no way to specify the iterator type explicitly, because it contains capturing closures.

Comment: You say that "I do not want to allocate on the heap". Unless you are in a no_std environment or on some highly restricted embedded platform, that seems like a mistake.