# How to implement IntoIterator from nested map calls in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, nested, iterator, traits

I am having trouble specifying the IntoIterator's IntoIter associated type's type when implementing IntoIterator for a custom struct. Because the into_iter function calls a map that itself returns a map, and because if I remember correctly closures infer a new lifetime by default (or something like that) I am drowning in a generic soup that I just can't seem to figure out. This sounds contraptious already so I am gonna post the code snippet instead, and try to explain the expected behavior.

Note that I am quite confused on what's happening, so the question I asked might not be appropriate or could be better formulated, feel free to suggest a better one so I can update it.

In this code, we have a struct (SubstitutionBlock) that represents many substitutions (many SubstitutionEntry) in a concise manner. The need here is to "split" that concise representation (SubstitutionBlock) into an iteration of individual entries (multiple SubstitutionEntry). I am trying to implement IntoIterator for SubstitutionBlock, to yield SubstitutionEntry objects, but like I said, I just cannot figure out how.

After spending a whole afternoon on that, I am more interested in the solution to that code than in a workaround/alternative logic, but by all means, if you do think there is a better way to achieve that, feel free to post it.

I am posting a snippet for completness' sake but I believe a playground link is more useful :

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use+std%3A%3A%7Bcollections%3A%3AHashMap%2C+iter%3A%3AMap%7D%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Debug%29%5D%0Apub+struct+SubstitutionBlock+%7B%0A++++pub+id%3A+String%2C%0A++++pub+aliases%3A+HashMap%3CString%2C+Vec%3CString%3E%3E%2C%0A++++pub+format%3A+Option%3CString%3E%2C%0A++++pub+parents%3A+Option%3CVec%3CString%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Debug%29%5D%0Astruct+SubstitutionEntry+%7B%0A++++id%3A+String%2C%0A++++alias%3A+String%2C%0A++++value%3A+String%2C%0A++++format%3A+Option%3CString%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl+IntoIterator+for+SubstitutionBlock+%7B%0A++++type+Item+%3D+SubstitutionEntry%3B%0A++++%0A++++%2F%2F%2F+HERE+IS+WHERE+I+STRUGGLE%0A++++%2F%2F+type+IntoIter%3C%27a%3E+%3D+Map%3CHashMap%3CString%2C+Vec%3CString%3E%3E%2C+fn%28%28%26%27a+String%2C+%26%27a+Vec%3CString%3E%29%29+-%3E+Map%3C%26%27a+Vec%3CString%3E%2C+fn%28%26String%29+-%3E+SubstitutionEntry%3E%3E%3B%0A++++type+IntoIter+%3D+Map%3CHashMap%3CString%2C+Vec%3CString%3E%3E%2C+fn%28%28%26String%2C+%26Vec%3CString%3E%29%29+-%3E+Map%3C%26Vec%3CString%3E%2C+fn%28%26String%29+-%3E+SubstitutionEntry%3E%3E%3B%0A%0A++++fn+into_iter%28self%29+-%3E+Self%3A%3AIntoIter+%7B%0A%0A++++++++self.aliases%0A++++++++.into_iter%28%29%0A++++++++.map%28%0A++++++++++++%7C%28value%2C+aliases%29%7C+aliases.into_iter%28%29.map%28%0A++++++++++++++++%7Calias%7C+SubstitutionEntry%7B%0A++++++++++++++++++++id%3A+self.id.to_owned%28%29%2C%0A++++++++++++++++++++alias%3A+alias.to_owned%28%29%2C%0A++++++++++++++++++++value%3A+value.to_owned%28%29%2C%0A++++++++++++++++++++format%3A+self.format.to_owned%28%29%2C%0A++++++++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++++++%29%0A++++++++%29%0A%0A++++%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++%0A++++let+sb+%3D+SubstitutionBlock%7B%0A++++++++id%3A+String%3A%3Afrom%28%22id0%22%29%2C%0A++++++++aliases%3A+HashMap%3A%3Afrom%28%5B%0A++++++++++++%28%22value0%22%2C+vec%21%5B%22alias0%2C+alias1%2C+alias2%22%5D%29%2C%0A++++++++%5D%29%2C%0A++++++++format%3A+None%2C%0A++++++++parents%3A+None%2C%0A++++%7D%3B%0A++++%0A++++for+entry+in+sb.into_iter%28%29+%7B%0A++++++++println%21%28%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C+entry%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A)

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, iter::Map};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SubstitutionBlock {
    pub id: String,
    pub aliases: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>,
    pub format: Option<String>,
    pub parents: Option<Vec<String>>,
}


#[derive(Debug)]
struct SubstitutionEntry {
    id: String,
    alias: String,
    value: String,
    format: Option<String>,
}

impl IntoIterator for SubstitutionBlock {
    type Item = SubstitutionEntry;
    
    /// HERE IS WHERE I STRUGGLE
    // type IntoIter<'a> = Map<HashMap<String, Vec<String>>, fn((&'a String, &'a Vec<String>)) -> Map<&'a Vec<String>, fn(&String) -> SubstitutionEntry>>;
    type IntoIter = Map<HashMap<String, Vec<String>>, fn((&String, &Vec<String>)) -> Map<&Vec<String>, fn(&String) -> SubstitutionEntry>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {

        self.aliases
        .into_iter()
        .map(
            |(value, aliases)| aliases.into_iter().map(
                |alias| SubstitutionEntry{
                    id: self.id.to_owned(),
                    alias: alias.to_owned(),
                    value: value.to_owned(),
                    format: self.format.to_owned(),
                }
            )
        )

    }

}


fn main() {
    
    let sb = SubstitutionBlock{
        id: String::from("id0"),
        aliases: HashMap::from([
            ("value0", vec!["alias0, alias1, alias2"]),
        ]),
        format: None,
        parents: None,
    };
    
    for entry in sb.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", entry);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the outer `map()` be a `flat_map()`?

Comment: I did not know about flat_map() ... I thought that something like that might exist so I searched the iterator methods in the documentation, but somehow I missed it ... Guess I let frustration get the best of me once more ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is slightly impossible.

First, here is the body of the function fixed so that it compiles as a free-standing function. None of your closures need lifetimes since they all take owned values.

```rs
fn into_iter(block: SubstitutionBlock) -> impl Iterator<Item = SubstitutionEntry> {
    block.aliases.into_iter().flat_map(move |(value, aliases)| {
        let id = block.id.clone();
        let format = block.format.clone();

        aliases.into_iter().map(move |alias| SubstitutionEntry {
            id: id.clone(),
            alias,
            value: value.clone(),
            format: format.clone(),
        })
    })
}
```

The impossible part is that you can't return an opaque type from a trait method. You can replace `impl Iterator<Item = SubstitutionEntry>` with nearly the full type, but when you get to the closure type on `Map`, you will be stuck using `impl FnMut`, an opaque type. The best solution right now is to box them. You can box the closures, but I've boxed the entire thing since it's simpler.

```rs
type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = SubstitutionEntry>>;

fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
    let iter = into_iter(self);
    Box::new(iter)
}
```

This is what [async-trait](https://docs.rs/async-trait/) does.

Another way to get around this on a case-by-case basis is to create a struct that implements `Iterator` and have your logic inside of its `next` method instead of using `map`. It's a bit tedious to recreate the logic of `flat_map`, but this method of replacing a series of iterator adapters with a custom struct is always possible.

```rs
use std::collections::hash_map::IntoIter as HashIter;
use std::vec::IntoIter as VecIter;

pub struct SubstitutionIter {
    id: String,
    aliases: HashIter<String, Vec<String>>,
    format: Option<String>,
    current: Option<(String, VecIter<String>)>,
}

impl SubstitutionIter {
    fn new(sub: SubstitutionBlock) -> Self {
        let mut aliases = sub.aliases.into_iter();
        let current = aliases.next().map(|(k, v)| (k, v.into_iter()));

        Self {
            id: sub.id,
            aliases,
            format: sub.format,
            current,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SubstitutionIter {
    type Item = SubstitutionEntry;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let Some((alias, values)) = &mut self.current else {
            return None;
        };

        let next = Some(SubstitutionEntry {
            id: self.id.clone(),
            alias: alias.clone(),
            value: values.next().unwrap(),
            format: self.format.clone(),
        });

        if values.len() == 0 {
            self.current = self.aliases.next().map(|(k, v)| (k, v.into_iter()));
        }

        next
    }
}

impl IntoIterator for SubstitutionBlock {
    type Item = SubstitutionEntry;
    type IntoIter = SubstitutionIter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        SubstitutionIter::new(self)
    }
}
```

[All of this in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1fede972568a2560dc2880cc446e43a4)

Related:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/6274355)
- [Is it possible to use `impl Trait` as a function's return type in a trait definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39482131/6274355)

Comment: No need to clone `value`.

Comment: Oh you right. I felt like there were too many clones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most idiomatic solution that is tho nightly only.

```rust
    use mini_alloc::hashbrown::HashMap;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct SubstitutionBlock {
        pub id: String,
        pub aliases: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>,
        pub format: Option<String>,
        pub parents: Option<Vec<String>>,
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct SubstitutionEntry {
        pub id: String,
        pub alias: String,
        pub value: String,
        pub format: Option<String>,
    }

    impl IntoIterator for SubstitutionBlock {
        type Item = SubstitutionEntry;

        // this requires nightly feature `impl_trait_in_assoc_type`
        type IntoIter = impl Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;

        fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
            let Self {
                id,
                aliases,
                format,
                ..
            } = self;
            aliases.into_iter().flat_map(move |(value, aliases)| {
                let (id, format) = (id.to_owned(), format.to_owned());
                aliases.into_iter().map(move |alias| SubstitutionEntry {
                    id: id.to_owned(),
                    alias: alias.to_owned(),
                    value: value.to_owned(),
                    format: format.to_owned(),
                })
            })
        }
    }
```