# Storing types in a HashMap to dynamically instantiate them

Tags: rust

I am trying to store structs in a `HashMap` keyed by string so that I can later create new objects by string. Think of a REST API where clients can get the server to instantiate a specific object by supplying a name.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

struct MyOtherStruct;

impl MyOtherStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("MyStruct", MyStruct);
    h.insert("MyOtherStruct", MyOtherStruct);

    // This is pseudo-code
    let obj = h.get("MyStruct").unwrap()::new();
}
```

As I expected, this doesn't work due to syntax errors:

```
error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, or an operator, found `::`
  --> src/main.rs:25:41
   |
25 |     let obj = h.get("MyStruct").unwrap()::new();
   |                                         ^^ expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, or an operator here
```

My second attempt was to store a reference to the `new` method of each struct instead of the types themselves.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

struct MyOtherStruct;

impl MyOtherStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("MyStruct", &MyStruct::new);
    h.insert("MyOtherStruct", &MyOtherStruct::new);

    let obj = h.get("MyStruct").unwrap()();
}
```

This fails because the `fn` items have different types and can't be stored in the same `HashMap`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:31
   |
22 |     h.insert("MyOtherStruct", &MyOtherStruct::new);
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn item, found a different fn item
   |
   = note: expected type `&fn() -> MyStruct {MyStruct::new}`
              found type `&fn() -> MyOtherStruct {MyOtherStruct::new}`
```

Since I'm pretty new to Rust, I'm out of ideas. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is ultimately fundamentally impossible. In Rust, local variables are stored on the stack, which means that they have to have a fixed size, *known at compile time*. Your construction requires the size of the value on the stack to be determined at runtime.

The closest alternative is to move to *trait objects*, which introduce a layer of indirection:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait NewThing {
    fn new(&self) -> Box<Thing>;
}
trait Thing {}

struct MyStruct;

impl NewThing for MyStruct {
    fn new(&self) -> Box<Thing> {
        Box::new(Self {})
    }
}
impl Thing for MyStruct {}

struct MyOtherStruct;

impl NewThing for MyOtherStruct {
    fn new(&self) -> Box<Thing> {
        Box::new(Self {})
    }
}
impl Thing for MyOtherStruct {}

fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<_, Box<NewThing>> = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("MyStruct", Box::new(MyStruct));
    h.insert("MyOtherStruct", Box::new(MyOtherStruct));

    let obj = h["MyStruct"].new();
}
```

You will find this pattern out in the world, such as in hyper's [`NewService`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.24/hyper/server/trait.NewService.html).

> what is [the value of `&self` of method `new`] when calling `h["MyStruct"].new()`

It's an instance of `MyStruct` or `MyOtherStruct`. The only reason that the same type can implement both traits is because there's no real unique state for the "factory" and the "instance". In more complicated implementations, these would be two different types.

Using the same type is common for such cases as sharing a reference-counted value.

See also:

- [Is it possible to have a constructor function in a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31897330/155423)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing I don't understand in your proposed alternative is the parameter `&self` of method `new` - what is its value when calling `h["MyStruct"].new()`?

Comment: @Tyrant it's an instance of `MyStruct` or `MyOtherStruct`. The only reason that the same type can implement both traits is because there's no real unique state for the "factory" and the "instance". In more complicated implementations, these would be two different types.

Comment: I think I got it now. I will update my post with a more complex example, using different types for "factory" and "instance". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complex example of @Shepmaster's solution, using different types for Factories and the objects themselves:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait NewThing {
    fn new(&self) -> Box<Thing>;
}
trait Thing {
    fn execute(&mut self);
}

// MyStruct
struct MyStructFactory;
impl NewThing for MyStructFactory {
    fn new(&self) -> Box<Thing> {
        Box::new(MyStruct {test: 12, name: "Test".into()})
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    test: i32,
    name: String
}

impl Thing for MyStruct {
    fn execute(&mut self) { 
        self.test+=1;
        println!("MyStruct {} {}", self.test, self.name);
    }
}

// MyOtherStruct
struct MyOtherStructFactory;
impl NewThing for MyOtherStructFactory {
    fn new(&self) -> Box<Thing> {
        Box::new(MyOtherStruct {my_member: 1})
    }
}

struct MyOtherStruct {
    my_member: u32
}

impl Thing for MyOtherStruct {
    fn execute(&mut self) { println!("MyOtherStruct.my_member: {}", self.my_member); }
}

fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<_, Box<NewThing>> = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("MyStruct", Box::new(MyStructFactory));
    h.insert("MyOtherStruct", Box::new(MyOtherStructFactory));

    h["MyStruct"].new().execute();
    h["MyOtherStruct"].new().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::any::Any` to erase the type of the entry. They use `Any::downcast<T>` to check if the entry at the location matches your type, and get a `Ok(Box<T>)`